# Get an element in a Set with "member"

Tags: objective-c, swift, set

I'm quite new to Swift and I'm trying to re-write a piece of Objective-C code into the Swift language. The original code is modifying an element in a Set:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) NSMutableSet<CustomItem *> *itemsSet;
...

CustomItem *item = [[CustomItem alloc] initWithSomething:something];
CustomItem *existingItem = [self.itemsSet member:item];
if (existingItem) {
    existingItem.property = 3
}
```

The Swift code looks something like this:

```
var itemsSet = Set<CustomItem>()
...

let item = CustomItem(something: something)
let existingItem = self.itemsSet...?
```

Is it possible to get the Set's element in a similar fashion using Swift?

Comment: It actually does not seem that `member` is available for swift. The docs state *A shadow for the "core operations" of NSSet. ... `public func member(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject?`*  which sounds like it is not available for Swift :/ I am confused by this.

Comment: If you use the old fashioned `NSMutableSet` instead it will work.

Comment: The `remove` method returns the object, guess could use that and then re-insert the object.
Seems like an oversight. The `contains` method is the analogue of the `member` method but it only returns a `bool` unlike the Objective C version.
Note, according to the docs, "Swift’s Set type is bridged to Foundation’s NSSet class."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unfortunately have no idea as to *why* this does not work as expected. I would have assumed that the Swift `Set` has a `member` function as well - apparently it **does not**.

In the documentation of the `Swift` module the following is written:

```
/// A shadow for the "core operations" of NSSet.
///
/// Covers a set of operations everyone needs to implement in order to
/// be a useful `NSSet` subclass.
@objc public protocol _NSSetCoreType : _NSCopyingType, _NSFastEnumerationType {
    public init(objects: UnsafePointer<AnyObject?>, count: Int)
    public var count: Int { get }
    public func member(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject?
    public func objectEnumerator() -> _NSEnumeratorType
    public func copyWithZone(zone: _SwiftNSZone) -> AnyObject
    public func countByEnumeratingWithState(state: UnsafeMutablePointer<_SwiftNSFastEnumerationState>, objects: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject>, count: Int) -> Int
}
```

which *sounds* like all those functions are not available in Swift (I might be wrong about this one but it seems to be true).

One workaround for this is to use a `NSMutableSet` (the same type as in Objective-C):

```
var itemsSet : NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet()
itemsSet.addObject("bla")
let existingItem = itemsSet.member("bla")
```

The other one is to write slightly more code but stay in "Swift territory":

```
let item = CustomItem(something: "")
if let index = itemsSet.indexOf(item) {
    let existingItem = itemsSet[index]
    existingItem.something = "somethingElse"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `indexOf()` and subscripting – as suggested in luk2302's answer –
seems a good and Swifty solution to me.

But just for the sake of completeness: You *can* use the `member()`
method of `NSSet`, you just have to cast `Set` to `NSSet`
explicitly:

```
if let existingItem = (itemsSet as NSSet).member(item) as? CustomItem {
    existingItem.something = "somethingElse"
}
```

Comment: Since you are little bit more heavily involved into Swift @MartinR, do know anything more about the *"shadow for the "core operations" of NSSet"*-statement?

Comment: @luk2302: No (and I am not sure if I am), I never noticed that before. – But _NSSetCoreType is a protocol and I cannot see that any type is declared as conforming to it.

Comment: Me neither. That is why I am so confused about it. I think there is some *magic* going on here with the protocol hiding some Objective-C API.